# Loading many videos in WPF (.NET 4)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, video, mediaelement

I am developing a WPF application (in .NET 4) which 
contains a lot of videos (40 videos, each video > 1 G) using the WPF 
media element. Unfortunately, I cannot load more than 10 videos at a 
time. When I try to display more videos, a black screen appears
where normally the video should be played.

Has anyone ever experienced such a problem and found a solution? It would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time, I found the solution: calling 'close' on a mediaelement frees the memory... .

Comment: I'm resurrecting an old topic here, but I am having the same issue with an app I'm writing. 10 simultaneous vids, and beyond that no display.  Seems the max is 10 on screen at once.  Sometimes just 9.  My vids are very small and short, but 9-10 still seems to be the limit.